# Bass measure and treble measure don't add up

Tags: notation

I'm having trouble matching the length of the two measures in the image below. All rests are eighth rests. Up until the seventh note group in the bass, things align; note groups 5 and 6 are sixteenths and they eat up the corresponding quarter rest in the treble measure, but then things get weird. If I start matching up from the right, the last two rests and the last two groups of notes match up, which leaves me with the quarter note to match with the eighth rest. That doesn't match up. Things don't add up.

To make matters more complicated, there's an extra eighth rest drawn in the bass measure; if it's meant to belong in the measure above, then the time intervals would at least add up.

This is Rachmaninov's Op 23 No 5.

[image: Mismatched measure]

This piece seems buggy from the first measure, as it's missing a couple of rests in the middle of the first measure:

[image]

Comment: In the first image, the notes that are vertically aligned are to be played at the same time. The half note is meant to be held for the rest of the measure even though there are two more 8th notes for the left hand to play.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Can you turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If someone doesn’t beat me to it, I will. I don’t have time to type a real answer just now

Comment: OK. Looks real enough to me already, though. :)